# Bing Maps C# GPX Route Viewer won't compile: cannot convert from LocationCollection to LocationRect

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-8, bing-maps, windows-store-apps

The Bing Windows Store sample app "Bing Maps C# GPX Route Viewer" won't compile.

On this line of code:

```
LocationRect bestRouteView = new LocationRect(gpxRoutePoints);
```

...I get these two err msgs:

*The best overloaded method match for 'Bing.Maps.LocationRect.LocationRect(Bing.Maps.LocationRect)' has some invalid arguments*

*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Bing.Maps.LocationCollection' to 'Bing.Maps.LocationRect'*

(gpxRoutePoints is a LocationCollection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you're using was recently updated to the [RTM version of the Bing Maps SDK](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca), and the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846491.aspx) it's complaining about was introduced there.  [Install the SDK update](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca) and you should be fine.